# Ho to trigger a job in the database and disconnect, instead of keeping a connection open for a long time?

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc

I have a heavily loaded database. When I open a connection and trigger a job/query, it's taking a lot of time to complete (more than 15 min). Until that time my connection with the database is open, but timeout and other issues occurs after 10 minutes.

Is there any way by which I can trigger a job in Oracle from Java or something so that :

1. I open the connection.
2. I trigger that "something".
3. I close the connection.

So that these 3 steps take less time, 1 minute or so.

Comment: Hi, do you know why you have slow connection?

Comment: Is that `something` a db operation requiring db connection, or in some way dependent on db connection? If not, you can create a new thread to hand over that `something` to a new thread

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DBMS_SCHEDULER` package](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#i1000363) for that:

```
exec DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
 'myjob',
 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
 'BEGIN do_something(); END;'
);
```

Note that you cannot return query results from a job, obviously. If you want a result set, you will need to write it to a file (e.g. using UTL_FILE), an external table, or a regular database table.

Comment: No, i dont want any resultset. Just what i want is to hit the database, do the processing. Since that processing is taking more time, I want an option. @mustaccio